# AppBarLayout scrolling behavior not working for nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a `MainActivity` with a `FrameLayout` placeholder where I switch in/out fragments based on the NavigationView selection. I want to be able to have the MainActivity Toolbar scroll off screen when it encounters a scroll behavior in *any* fragment it contains (even nested fragments).

It works well for `HomeFragment (1)`, which only contains a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and a `RecyclerView`.

**However**, for the `ViewPagerFragment (2)`, which contains a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and child fragments of type `ViewPagerItemFragment (3)`, it fails to register scroll events on the `ViewPagerItemFragment's` containing `RecyclerView`.

Complete layouts (stripped of theming or unnecessary attributes) are below.

**layout_activity_main:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center">

                    <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**layout_home_fragment (1):**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**layout_fragment_viewpager (2):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_strip_height"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_viewpager_item (3):**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, apparently I was using another CoordinatorLayout inside another container parent without realizing it. Just make sure you don't have multiple containing CoordinatorLayouts, it will screw up your layouts inside your inner Fragments.

Comment: good question and thanks for the answer. but if we need a coordinator layout inside our fragment, what do we do ? I have a fragment that have coordinator layout , appbar and collapse layout inside it own. not using coordinator layout in every fragment is Inevitable.